# what is the Friend class of a derived class relation with parent class?

Tags: c++

how can a friend class(F) of a derived class(D) access the private or protected members of parent class(P) of D. Or is there no way to do so?

Comment: The only ways a `friend` of a derived class can access `private` or `protected` members of a base class are (1)  the `friend` *is* the base class (i.e. the derived class declares its base as a `friend`)  or  (2)   the base class ALSO declares that class as a `friend`.      A derived class cannot arbitrarily grant access to `protected` or `private` members of the base class to some other class *by design* - if it could, that would defeat the purpose of `protected` and `private` access specifiers.

Comment: @Peter A friend of a derived class can access public or protected members of the base class, exactly the same way the derived class itself can access them.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.    A `friend` of the derived class can access `protected` members of the derived class, and that includes `protected` members that the derived class instance inherits from the base class.    The `friend` of the derived class cannot access `protected` or `private` members of ANOTHER INSTANCE of the base class.   Also, if a `friend` of the derived class is passed a reference to the base (i.e. a `base &`) it cannot access `protected` or `public` members via that reference

Comment: @Peter yes of course, the same way the derived class itself cannot.

Answer (score 0):

C++ FAQ on this exact issue here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends#friendship-not-inherited-transitive